# How to change button image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I change the image of a button from form 3 to form 2? I use those buttons to navigate between forms, and want to, when I click on button in form 3, to get back to form 2, to have changed the picture of button in form 2.

This is how I navigate between forms.

**FORM2 BUTTON**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 m = new Form3();
    m.Show();
    this.Visible = false;
    this.Hide();
}
```

**FORM3 BUTTON**

```
 private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form2 m = new Form2();
     m.Show();
     this.Visible = false;
     this.Hide();
 }
```

Comment: How are you defining your images? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BrankoBrka, this is not very difficult in regards to changing the Image of a button.. also there are plenty of tutorials and examples on line in regards to changing  the `Button.Image`

Comment: also I would suggest that you change the names of your buttons to make more sense even if you are the only one maintaining your code so you don't get all confused if you can change in one form you can change in another not sure where the confusion is coming in.. and what do you mean provide a link are you saying `Google or some other Search Engine` does not work from your part of the world..?

Answer (score 2):

In your button on FORM 3, do something like this:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 m = new Form2();
    m.button1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
    m.Show();
    this.Visible = false;
    this.Hide();
}
```

In order for this to work, the `button1` on your FORM 3 must be accessible. So go to FORM 3 and mark `button1` as `public`.

Comment: personally I would suggest to the OP to use 
`m.Button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.*Image_Identifier*;` //meaning the name of the resource file image name the avoids having to use Paths in case the file path is not there etc...

Comment: @MethodMan That's if you already have the image in your resources. I agree that you need to handle the exceptions for the path, but I think the OP knows that. He only wanted to know how to access controls (e.g. button) on another form.

Comment: based on my suggestion they would need to have the file as a resource..that's pretty much a no brainer.. either way my point is there are much easier ways of skinning this same cat..

Comment: I think your answer is clear enough but I disagree that the OP knows about resource files and or paths etc.. because based on what they have written in their original question had nothing to do with what your'e saying.. either way this issue could have been resolved in like under 5 seconds doing a simple google search

Comment: @MethodMan i tried the method but doesnt work.
says **'Projekat.Form2.button1' is inaccessible due to its protection level**

Comment: @BrankoBrka are you familiar with that error message..? do you know what the difference between `public, private, protected...etc` you need to change the button default property in the designer from `private to public` I would recommend you doing some reading on `Encapsulation` and 
[C# MSDN  Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) why don't you change your button names to mean something also update your question with the code that you have tried..

Comment: @MethodMan i figured it out just as you posted. i do undestand its just its all new to me, benn doing this for less than a month... tnx for the help.

Comment: @BrankoBrka Go to FORM 3 and change the `button1` to `public`. I will edit my answer to show that.

Comment: @BrankoBrka not a problem.. what I am getting at is basically that `MSDN` has tons of examples online and is a valuable resource as well as the rest of the Internet regardless of time served using C#

Comment: @MethodMan I did not say that the OP knows about the resources and path, etc. I don't know what OP know, so I wouldn't make such a claim. What I said was that I think the OP knows how to handle exceptions (i.e. simply wrap that line with a `try...catch`) because that's very basic concept in programming.

Comment: I am leaving this one alone since the OP has only been doing this a couple days I don't think they are at that level of simplicity yet.. Cheers.. !! `Plus 1` for your answer btw :)